# HighCharts event on column category name click

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'd like an event to fire if a user clicks the category name of a column chart.  I see there are options for if the user [clicks the bar itself](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click), but what about the category name of the bar?

Comment: What do you mean by "name of a bar"? Is it the labels for the categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
$("#container .highcharts-axis-labels:first text").click(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0mu8s664/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom-events](https://github.com/blacklabel/custom_events) plugin, which extends events in chart.

Comment: This may work, but I'd rather not add the external dependency.