# react-highcarts using es6 getting some errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, ecmascript-6, react-highcharts

I am new to react library and es6 and I tried to build a graph that display data. I started with creating the react app template and then I decided to use  highchart and start playing with their xrange graph.
Im using https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts library.

My Code looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';

class Graph extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            config:  {
                chart: {
                    type: 'xrange'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Highcharts X-range'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    categories: ['Prototyping', 'Development', 'Testing'],
                    reversed: true
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Project 1',
                    // pointPadding: 0,
                    // groupPadding: 0,
                    pointWidth: 20,
                    data: [{
                        x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
                        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                        y: 0,
                        partialFill: 0.25
                    }, {
                        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
                        y: 1
                    }, {
                        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
                        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                        y: 2
                    }, {
                        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
                        y: 1
                    }, {
                        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
                        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
                        y: 2
                    }],
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }]

            }
        }
    }
    render() {
        const config = this.state.config;
        return (
            <ReactHighcharts config={config}></ReactHighcharts>
        )
    }
}


export default Graph
```

My final design is going to be importing a default template and inject to the component properties like title and data to make it a little more flexible.

Im getting 2 errors (I just copy the xrange graph from highcharts website):

1. Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
2. TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow error link https://www.highcharts.com/errors/17  which state

> This error happens when you are setting chart.type or series.type to a series type that isn't defined in Highcharts. A typical reason may be that your are missing the extension file where the series type is defined, for example in order to run an arearange series you need to load the highcharts-more.js file.

Import highcharts more js

```
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';
import xrange from 'highcharts/modules/xrange';
(xrange)(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts)
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-highcharts-xrange-demo?file=index.js)

Comment: Thank a lot! Do you know any way to trigger event from clicking on Y-axis categories?

Comment: this post works https://stackoverflow.com/a/31737990/3898339 but it is not in react. Add new post some one may help